# Should I apply a min-max scale (range 0 to 1) before applying the normalisation or should I apply the z-score normalisation directly?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing, image-segmentation, normalisation

I want to implement a neural network in Pytorch for medical image segmentation. I should normalise my data.

Should I apply a min-max scale (range 0 to 1) before applying the normalisation or should I apply the z-score normalisation directly?

1. What is the best approach if the dataset comes from a single source of data?
2. What if the samples come from multiple sources?

Answer (score 2):

There is, beside of numerical *losses* not difference between directly using z-normalization and first min-max and then z-normalization.

###### Explanation

Both are affine transformations and a combination of affine transformations is again an affine transformation. Since there is only one(*) affine transformation that results on zero-mean and variance of one, the z-normalization will (kind of) undo all previous affine transformations to achieve this goal.

(*): In fact there are two and you could get the other by multiplying every value with -1. But this is just a silly detail and does not matter for this question.